# duplicated list fields in documnt's properties

Tags: sharepoint-2010, content-type

I have one site columns which is added to an existing Content Type that has been deployed via a Feature.
In the Content Type, the columns appear fine, but when viewing or editing the properties of a document which its list used the content type, the columns appear twice.  They appear identical and updating one of the instances updates both instances.  Looking at the available fields using PowerShell on the List Item and on the Site Collection does not show any duplication - the same is true when viewing the Library Settings and viewing the columns.  Despite this, the duplication still happens when viewing or editing properties.
here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- My Column (Field)-->
  <Field ID="{996A0BA7-4B25-44F9-9AE6-FBE47EC123CE}" Group="RK Fields" Name="Kategori" DisplayName="Kategori" Type="Text" 
         Hidden="TRUE" Required="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Kategori"/>

  <!-- My Content Type -->
  <ContentType ID="0x01010053e1d612ba3f4e21aa250ecd751942b3"
               Name="RKDokument"
              Group="RK Content Types"
              Description="Innehållstyp för dokument på RK"
              Inherits="TRUE"
              Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{996A0BA7-4B25-44F9-9AE6-FBE47EC123CE}" Name="Kategori" />
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes I find the solution, if you have a field which has a displayname is same is a buildin field it will get both.